# Powers of natural numbers.

Tags: terminology, natural-numbers

Is there a term for a natural number $N$ which cannot be expressed in the form $a^b$ where $a$ and $b$ are both naturals not equal to $N$?

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Numbers of the form $a^b$ are called *perfect powers*. So perhaps *non-powers*, or *imperfect numbers*, or simply *Cheese-numbers*.

Comment: @DietrichBurde "Imperfect" sounds like "not perfect" , so I prefer "non-powers".